# SQL Server full-text search for phrase containing a hyphen doesn't return expected results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, full-text-search

We have an application that using a SQL Server 2008 database, and full-text search. I'm trying to understand why the following searches behave differently:

First, a phrase containing a hyphenated word, like this:

```
contains(column_name, '"one two-three-four five"')
```

And second, an identical phrase, where the hyphens are replaced by spaces:

```
contains(column_name, '"one two three four five"')
```

The full-text index uses the ENGLISH (1033) locale, and the default system stoplist.

From my observations of other full-text searches containing hyphenated words, the first one should allow for matches on either `one two three four five` or `one twothreefour five`. Instead, it only matches `one twothreefour five` (and not `one two-three-four five`).

---

**Test Case**

Setup:

```
create table ftTest 
(
    Id int identity(1,1) not null, 
    Value nvarchar(100) not null, 
    constraint PK_ftTest primary key (Id)
);

insert ftTest (Value) values ('one two-three-four five');
insert ftTest (Value) values ('one twothreefour five');

create fulltext catalog ftTest_catalog;
create fulltext index on ftTest (Value language 1033)
    key index PK_ftTest on ftTest_catalog;
GO
```

Queries:

```
--returns one match
select * from ftTest where contains(Value, '"one two-three-four five"')

--returns two matches
select * from ftTest where contains(Value, '"one two three four five"')
select * from ftTest where contains(Value, 'one and "two-three-four five"')
select * from ftTest where contains(Value, '"one two-three-four" and five')
GO
```

Cleanup:

```
drop fulltext index on ftTest
drop fulltext catalog ftTest_catalog;
drop table ftTest;
```

Answer (score 10):

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;200043

"Where non-alphanumeric character must be used in the search critera (primarily the dash '-' character), use the Transact-SQL LIKE clause instead of the FULLTEXT or CONTAINS predicates."

Comment: The question is more about *why* SQL server exhibits different behaviour for matching.  Working around it is certainly doable, but it simply doesn't make sense to me that "two-three-four five" will return both rows, however "one two-three-four five" will not.  Ditto for "one two-three-four".  Is this really expected behaviour? and if so, why?

Answer (score 10):

In cases like these where you can't anticipate the behavior of the word-breaker it's always a good idea to run sys.dm_fts_parser on your strings to get an idea of how the words are going to be split and stored in the internal index.

For instance, running sys.dm_fts_parser on '"one two-three-four five"' results in the following -

```
select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('"one two-three-four five"', 1033, NULL, 0)
--edited--
1   0   1   Exact Match one
1   0   2   Exact Match two-three-four
1   0   2   Exact Match two
1   0   3   Exact Match three
1   0   4   Exact Match four
1   0   5   Exact Match five
```

As you can see from the returned results, the word-breaker parses the string and outputs six forms which may explain the results you see when running your CONTAINS query.

Answer (score 3):

A full-text search considers a word to be a string of characters without spaces or punctuation. The occurrence of a non-alphanumeric character can "break" a word during a search. Because the SQL Server full-text search is a word-based engine, punctuation generally is not considered and is ignored when searching the index. Therefore, a CONTAINS clause like 'CONTAINS(testing, "computer-failure")' would match a row with the value, "The failure to find my computer would be expensive.".

Please, follow the link for WHY:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/200043