# SQL CONTAINSTABLE does not allow full stops

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use CONTAINSTABLE to filter a set of results by some search text which is passed in by the user. The search text in question -

```
declare @SearchText NVARCHAR(255) = N'"r.e*"'
```

As far as I can see the full stop is getting removed, and the search text becomes N'"r e*"' when it is put in as a parameter to CONTAINSTABLE below.

```
SELECT
        Name
    FROM
        uvw_ResourceSearch R
    JOIN
        CONTAINSTABLE(uvw_ResourceSearch , *, @SearchText) Resource_Search
        ON R.Id = Resource_Search.[Key]
```

The correct results where the resource name contains a full stop are never returned because it is being removed. Does anyone know a way to escape the character in some fashion, or an alternative method that could be used?

Comment: `CONTAINSTABLE` follows the rules of `CONTAINS`, and ["punctuation is ignored"](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql). [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11642886/4137916). You may be trying to do things that full-text search isn't equipped to do; to index and search for a very short phrase with punctuation you'd probably need to change the default word breakers, which seems quite complicated.

Comment: Yeah I was having a look at that page before on the contains rule, and was wondering/hoping there was a way around it. You have more or less confirmed my suspicions that there is not an easy way of doing what I'm trying to do, so I'll start looking for a different method.